Why would the Euler-Lagrange equations here be a function of $q$?
For any function $ L(q,\dot{q}) $, the functional $$S = \int_{}{}{L}{\, \mathrm{d}t}$$ is minimised through the Euler-Lagrange equations: $$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial q} - \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}t}\frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{q}} = 0.$$ For the standard Lagrangian $L = \dfrac{1}{2}\dot{q}^2 - V(q)$ this yields the Euler-Lagrange equation: $$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2 q}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial q}.$$ In S. Coleman, Fate of the False Vacuum I, it is stated that the above equation also minimises the functional $$\int \sqrt{2(E - V) } \, \mathrm{d}s $$ where $E$ is given as $$ E = \frac{1}{2} \dot{q}^2 + V.$$ Subbing this in, however, I find that the "Lagrangian" reduces to simply $L = |\dot{q}|$ and the Euler-Lagrange equations no longer yield the same equation. Can anyone explain to me why the standard Lagrangian equation can still be used here? I don't quite follow.
EDIT: Here is the passage from the text:

$$\delta \int \mathrm{d}s \sqrt{2(E-V)}=0,\tag{2.8}$$
with fixed end points, are the paths in configuration space traced out by solutions to Euler-Lagrange equations
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}^2\vec q}{\mathrm{d}t^2} = - \frac{\partial V}{\partial \vec q},\tag{2.9}$$
with
$$\frac{1}{2}\frac{\mathrm{d}\vec q}{\mathrm{d}t}\cdot \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec q}{\mathrm{d}t}+V = E. \tag{2.10}$$


Hint: Doesn't using $L=\dot q$ in the Euler Lagrange equation give you 0=0?

Attached the relevant text from the paper, the function we're trying to minimise is definitely $\sqrt{2(E-V)}$. I found subbing in L = $\dot{q}$ did give 0=0; is this not a dead end? I don't see how to derive (2.9) from there.

Typically $L = E-V$ therefore, i gues $V$ depends on $q$

Hints:

Eq. (2.8) is the "Jacobi form of the abbreviated action/Maupertuis principle", cf. e.g. Ref. 1.

Note that $\dot{q}$ is hidden inside the measure:
$$\mathrm{d}s ~=~\sqrt{(\mathrm{d}q)^2} ~=~\sqrt{\dot{q}^2}\mathrm{d}\lambda, \qquad \dot{q}~:=~\dfrac{\mathrm{d}q}{\mathrm{d}\lambda},$$ where $\lambda$ is the independent variable/parameter.

It is tempting to consider an extended Lagrangian
$$ \widetilde{L}~=~\frac{\dot{q}^2}{2e}+(E-V)e, $$
where $e>0$ is an einbein field. If we integrate out/eliminate the $e$ field, we return$^1$ to the square root action (2.8). The stationary action principle (with its Euler-Lagrange equations) corresponds to the gauge $e=1$.


References:

H. Goldstein, Classical Mechanics; eq. (8.89).


$^1$ This is similar to the relativistic point particle.

Thank you this was helpful. As the problem is time-independent I see why they use the abbreviated action rather than the true action here. Is it fine to use the Euler-Lagrange equations for "true" action in any scenario where the system is independent of time? ie. the action reduces to the abbreviated action in any time-independent system with constant energy?
